# Count the number of words in a string in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How can I count the number of words in a string?

For example:

```
str = 'hi how are you'  % Expected: 4
str = 'hi'              % Expected: 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can  use `strsplit` to split a string at all spaces (returns a cell array where each element is a word) and then determine the number of elements in the resulting cell array

```
nWords = numel(strsplit(str));
```

Alternately, if you have an older version of MATLAB you can use `regexp` to do the splitting for you.

```
nWords = numel(regexp(str, '\s+', 'split'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions:

```
str = 'hi, how are you?';
matches = regexpi(str, '\w+');
N = numel(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to worry about multiple spaces screwing things up, in 16b you could do

```
num = count(str,' ') + 1;
```